# How to extract attribute name and amount of max co-occurrence count in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Given a dataframe `df` in the format

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J ...
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0 ...
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0 ...
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

I'd like to end up with a results dataframe in the format

```
   corr  count
A   B     270
B   F      15
C   J     100
.   .       .
.   .       .
.   .       .
```

where for each row, `corr` is the column with the max co-occurrence and `count` is the co-occurrence count.

My current code looks like this:

```
cooccurring_df = df.T.dot(df)
np.fill_diagonal(cooccurring_df.values, 0)
idxmax_df = pd.DataFrame(cooccurring_df.idxmax(axis = 0), columns=['corr'])
```

which gives:

```
   corr 
A   B 
B   F   
C   J  
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the count properly assigned from `cooccuring_df` into `idxmax_df`. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and I'm sure there's a better way to get to where I want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for is `lookup`:

```
idxmax_df['count'] = cooccurring_df.lookup(idxmax_df.index, idxmax_df['corr'])
```

Test data:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Output (for the given data)

```
  corr  count
A    B      1
B    F      2
C    J      1
D    A      0
E    A      1
F    B      2
G    A      0
H    A      0
I    A      0
J    C      1
```

Comment: That works perfecly. Is there a more efficient / intuitive way to go from `df` to `idxmax_df`?

Comment: `count` can be built by `coorcurring_df.max(axis=0)`. But that's not really better since you already have `idxmax`. Your solution looks really good. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I'm realizing another issue with my code is that it generates a spurious value for the `corr` field when the count is 0 - that should be `NaN`. 

Which I'm doing by another line of code:

`idxmax_df.loc[idxmax_df['count']==0,'corr'] = np.NaN`

(side note - somewhat bad form to use "count" as a field name)